# Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I have following component html code, but i'm getting interpolation error.

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4]; let i = index">
  <select #btn{{i}} (change)="myEvent(btn{{i}}.value)"
  ><option>A</option>
  <option>B</option><option>C</option></select>
</div>
```

how to get the drop down value?

Comment: `#btn{{i}}` doesn't work with Angular afaik. My workaround in the past has been to make a reusable component and just pass the data from the *ngFor as an input property. But you just have a select button so that might be a bit too much of a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use the reference `#btn` this will give you the reference for each iteration of `*ngFor` . Your template reference variable is already unique because you use it inside embedded view scope:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4]; let i = index">
  <select #btn (change)="myEvent(btn?.value)">
   <option>A</option>
   <option>B</option>
   <option>C</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: here `?` is  called `safe navigation operator` google it

Comment: its not  necessary.  but to write clean code  and  to make sure that you are not accessing property of null object in template . This operator can be used in all cases expect model binding  `[(ngModel)]="something.name"` for example in interpolation `{{  employee?.name }}`